# Sending out a javascript function call from a child window to a parent window function.

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I want to send out a javascript call from window B which is the child of Window A.
Lets say we have a window A with the js for the same being ajs.js and window B with the js for it being bjs.js
Window B opens within the container of Window A.
How can one send out a call from bjs.js to a ajs.js function?

Ext js 3.0/3.4
Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both windows are in the same domain, you can declare a method foo() on your parent, and call it in the child with

In the parent:

```
window.foo = function() { alert('called!'); }
```

From the child window:

```
window.parent.foo()
```

If they are not in the same domain, you won't be able to do this.  Depending on the version of your browser, you can you can use the window.postMessage method to pass information between windows.

Comment: Should that be only "foo" instead of "window.foo" when declaring/defining "foo" . I tried doing it with window.foo didnt work....works with simlpy "foo=function() { alert('called!'); }"

Comment: I'd have to see your code to figure out why - window.foo and foo should be the same.  Javascript "objects" declared in the global scope are attached to the window object.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call the functions in ajs.js from bjs.js using `window.parent` in winodw B. For example if you have function `foo()` in ajs.js, you can call it from window B using `window.parent.foo()`